# Displaying an image in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

- I have 3 Views as welcome.php, login.php and header-guest.php.
- I have included header-guest.php in both welcome.php and login.php as
  the header. (using a php include 'header-guest.php' )
- welcome.php is the opening/index page of the application and by
  clicking Login the "Welcome_controller" will redirect the user to
  login.php view.
- header-guest.php has the logo image which is logo.png (Resides in
  Public/img/logo.png) `<img src="Public/img/logo.png" />`
- The problem is, the image displays in welcome.php, but not in
  login.php. (Where both uses the same header)

Folder Structure is as follows

My Project

- application
- system
- Public->img->logo.png

Please instruct me to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as I see it, is that you are using a relative url as your image src.

Try using and absolute url for your image.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('Public/img/logo.png'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Hmm.. I updated the url. Did you use "Public/img/logo.png" as url ?

Comment: Yes I did that too :( In that way it doesn't show in both views, don't know why

Comment: Could you send the full URL to your image?   example http://www.mydomain.com/Public/img/logo.png

Comment: I guess your image is working when you access it like that. And your index.php is located at diluks-website/index.php ... than <img src="<?php base_url('Public/img/logo.png') ?>"/> should work. Could you right-click and check the source of your HTML, and see what the src is  like ?

Comment: Yes, You are right, Once I changed my project name, but I have'nt updated the base_url, Now I updated it, Your way works fine now! Thank You Soooo Much! I'm really sorry for my mistake